# tag prompts merge into one big block

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

Just now, I was editing the tags on a question. I clicked and started to delete a tag, then I noticed the little X on the tag prompts and thought "I wonder if that would be quicker", so I clicked out at the end of the list of tags, hoping to turn the plain text I had been about to edit back into an active tag prompt with an x. Instead, I got this:

[image]

I was able to reproduce at will.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Could you post some info on the browser and/or provide **exact** steps to reproduce this?

Comment: IE 8. Oddly it won't reproduce when the Windows 7 Problem Steps Recorder is running. Without it, I follow these steps: edit a post. Click on a tag turning it into plain text. Click out past the end of the last tag. Presto, one giant tag as in the image. Click inside the tag to turn the one you clicked on into plain text and the rest into buttons, then out at the end again to make a giant tag, etc.

Comment: can repro on IE9; in particlar: edit; click on **first** tag; click past **last** tag

Comment: No repro here on Firefox 3.old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery plugin we're using has a (admittedly clever, but) peculiar way to find the current selection in IE. This usually works fine, but fails in certain cases after a blur event (e.g. because you clicked on a different tag). Unfortunately, it fails in a way that broke my code :)

Fixed in the next build.